# Emitting a vue event from parent to child component in a laravel application without using event bus

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I seem to recall being able to emit an event from a parent component to a child component by specifying the emitted event in the opening `<template>` tag of the corresponding child component. However for some reason it is no longer working in my implementation. Am I delusional or was this possibly a feature from an older version of `VueJS` that was deprecated, possibly in place of the event bus architecture? I am currently using `Vue v2.6.12`.

In my $root vue instance:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    data: () => ({}),  
    methods: {
        clearForm() {
            this.$emit('clear-form');
        }
    }
});
```

Laravel layout:

```
<v-main>
    @yield('content')
</v-main>
```

Vue Router /Laravel view/vue:

```
@extends('layouts.user')

@section('content')
    <transition name="slide">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </transition>
@endsection
```

When `clearForm()` is called in the $root instance, shouldn't I be able to capture the emitted event in a child component like this...

```
<template @clear-form="clearForm"></template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            
        },
        created() {
            this.$on('clearForm', clearForm);
        }, 
        methods: {
            clearForm() {
                //this is the method i want to call when emitted from $root
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

The answer I selected from @JoshuaAngnoe is the correct method of passing an emitted event from a `$root Vue instance` to a child component served through `Vue-Router`. However in my case, I was also leveraging the `Laravel` framework, which adds an additional layer of complexity because the HTML is broken up into two files (layout & view).

The `Laravel` View, which houses the `<router-view>` element, is separate from the `Laravel` layout which is actually the same layer as the $root Vue instance. So an additional step is required to make it work...

The declaration for the emitted event, which in the chosen answer, resides within the `<router-view>` element: `<router-view @clear-form="clearForm" />` needs to be moved out of the `<router-view>` element, and into the opening template tag of the child component: `<template @clear-form="clearForm">`.

The structure of my initial example was correct. I was just missing `$root` when I called `$on` to capture the emitted event from the child component.

```
created() {
    this.$on('clearForm', clearForm);
}
```

Needed to be:

```
created() {
    this.$root.$on('clearForm', clearForm);
}
```

Comment: Parents pass stuff to children via props (a prop can be a function which can be run - basically acts as an event). Children emit events to parents. It's how it's always been, at least in 2.x. But really, you should decouple and use state. If you think Vuex is too much, give [Vue.observable()](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable) a spin. With state, you decouple everything and the store is your single source of truth, in sync throughout your app. Or, should I say: anywhere it's imported.

Comment: I can't pass a prop directly to the child. I'm using vue-router in a laravel layout, so the child component (i.e. the current main vue server by vue-router) is not actually specified. I know i have run into this problem before, I just forgot where I specified the passed prop/event in each child component/vue. If I remember correctly it was specified in the opening template tag of each vue served by the router.

Comment: you can pass parent function to child  `<ChildComponent :function="myFunction" />` like this then parent `myFunction` function will bind to child `function` this function

Comment: `<ChildComponent :method="parentMethod" />` like this

Comment: The problem is that the child component is not actually being specified. It is being dynamically injected via vue-router. So there never is a child component declaration such as `<ChildComponent :method="parentMethod" />`

Comment: @McWayWeb then your code is wrong `<router-view>` should be independent so it will have it's own logic and own style as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I delusional or was this possibly a feature from an older version of VueJS that was deprecated,

No you are not delusional, this was possible with Vue 1 if i recall correctly.

As you pointed out you are using Vue Router, it will be likely that a routed component will be responsible for triggering a clear-form event and you'd like your app to respond to that. That can be achieved by passing some listeners on `<router-view></router-view>`, like so `<router-view @clear-form="clearForm()"></router-view>`

An example:

```html
<div id="app">
  <h1>
  Hello
  </h1>
  <router-view @clear-form="clearForm"></router-view>
</div>
```

```js
Vue.use(VueRouter)
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  router: new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/', component: { template: `
        <div>
            Some page component
          <button @click="$emit('clear-form')">Clear form</button>
       </div>
      `} }
    ]
  }),
  
  methods: {
    clearForm() {
        alert("Clearing form")
    }
  }
});
```

Now the child component (route component) can send a signal to the App instance that the form should be cleared.

A working example in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zkfu8x5s/3/

Comment: I seem to have misread, the direction you want is Root -> Child instead of Child -> Parent... Anyways, passing event-listeners and params (even a callback function like Yasir suggested is possible.

Comment: Yes. I am trying to pass an emitted event from $root (parent) to child component (served with vue-router). The fiddle is an example of passing an event from child to parent.

Comment: I've updated the example to do it the other way around:
https://jsfiddle.net/bc31duse/1/
It basically uses the $root element as an event bus...

Comment: This is still emitting an event from child to parent/$root. I need to emit an event from $root/parent to child.

Comment: Yes, you are right, i did write the infrastructure but the button should be in the parent. I've fixed the fiddle to demonstrate a clear-form emitted from parent will be handled by the child here: https://jsfiddle.net/92n41ar7/3/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an event listener in a lifecycle  hook from your application (Created or BeforeMount or Mounted).

```
created() {
    this.$on('clear-form', function(){
        console.log('Event from child component emitted')
    });
 }
```

//or call your function

```
created() {
    this.$on('clear-form', clearForm) //<-- this function must be declared in your methods or actions
}
```

Comment: I updated the example to reflect what you suggested, however it is still not working. Could you clarify what is missing?

Comment: This can't work from Parent->Child only the other way round. Remember "Props down, Events up"

Answer (score 0):

Without using the event bus it is not possible.
Although there is another way to achieve this and that is using `props`.
The summary of that, in theory, is, pass a prop to the child component and add a watcher on that prop inside the child component. Now from a parent where you are currently emitting the event, all you need is to change the prop value and in the child component, the watcher will get executed.

Now in practicle,

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    data: () => ({
        clearForm: false,
    }),  
    methods: {
        clearForm() {
            this.clearForm = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Now pass this `clearForm` data attribute to your child component as a prop and add a watcher to listen for the change in this prop

```
<template></template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['clearForm'],
        data() {
            
        },
        created() {
          
        }, 
        methods: {
            clearFormFunc() {
                //this is the method i want to call when emitted from $root
            }
        },
        watch: {
            clearForm(value){
                if (value) {
                    this.clearFormFunc();
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Update 2**

You can listen on parents' events in the child component `created` or `mounted` hook by adding the following line of code in either of these hooks of the child component. Fire the event from the parent as you were firing it before, no need to change the parent.

```
this.$events.listen('clearForm', this.clearFormFunc);
```

Comment: The child component view is injected via vue-router so a traditional prop can't be passed because the name of the child component is never actually specified in order to be able to pass the prop. That's why I was attempting to bind it to the opening `<template>` tag of the child component.

Comment: How do you know that it is a child component if you have not used it inside a parent component?

Comment: in child component `created` or `mounted` hook you can listen to the event fired from parent using this 
`this.$events.listen('clearForm', this.clearFormFunc);`

Comment: I tried using `$events.listen()` in both `created()` & `mounted()` and neither of them worked.

Comment: How do you pass the prop from the $root instance to the child component served by vue-router if the child component is not explicitly stated?